# Obtaining the interpolation function of a surface

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

Some sample data

```
data = {{7.97028, 10., -3080}, {9.19676, 9.6, -3010}, 
    {8.50347, 10.1, -3162}, {9.92937, 9.6, -3090}, 
    {9.14074, 9.8, -3056}, {10.4484, 9.9, -3200}, 
    {8.06007, 10.1, -3130}, {9.82587, 9.8, -3090}, 
    {7.77652, 10.1, -3080}, {10.3784, 10.1, -3190}, 
    {8.77662, 10., -3119}, {8.96429, 10., -3115}, 
    {9.35687, 10., -3108}, {9.61884, 10., -3110}, 
    {9.95886, 9.7, -3100}, {8.12258, 9.7, -3000}, 
    {9.68049, 10.1, -3133}, {10.0694, 9.7, -3120}, 
    {7.7865, 10., -3050}, {8.97676, 9.8, -3055}, 
    {8.11848, 9.8, -3030}, {9.50436, 9.6, -3030}, 
    {8.66752, 9.9, -3085}, {10.1224, 9.6, -3130},
    {9.75226, 9.6, -3060}, {10.3547, 9.9, -3180}, 
    {10.1595, 9.8, -3140}, {10.2115, 9.8, -3150}, 
    {8.75025, 9.9, -3085}, {9.8972, 9.7, -3090}, 
    {10.0716, 10., -3140}, {8.60449, 10.1, -3162}, 
    {8.41269, 10.1, -3160}, {10.3654, 9.6, -3190},
    {7.93197, 10.1, -3110}, {10.4385, 9.8, -3200}, 
    {7.72951, 9.9, -3010}, {9.9803, 9.8, -3110}, 
    {7.52143, 10.1, -3020}, {7.9252, 9.8, -3010}, 
    {9.82945, 9.7, -3080}, {8.45747, 10., -3119}, 
    {9.97527, 10., -3130}, {9.8482, 10., -3120}, 
    {8.04631, 10., -3090}, {10.3021, 9.7, -3170}, 
    {10.1555, 10.1, -3160}, {9.60075, 9.6, -3040}, 
    {8.66849, 10.1, -3161}, {9.39444, 9.7, -3040}};
```

which define

```
L0 = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

My question: Is it possible to obtain the analytical expression $f(x,y,z)$ of the third order interpolated function used to create the above plot?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure for an unstructured grid, `InterpolationOrder` is ignored and you get an order-1 interpolation over `DelaunayMesh[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]`.  I.e., you get a piecewise interpolation by functions of the form `a + b y + x (c + d y)` over each triangle.  Solving for the coefficients over a given triangle is just a matter of setting up the linear equations.